# picture behind signUp form

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am doing a vue project,but I want to create a form to log in and put an image behind the form.
I tried, but when I put the image behind the form, it did not appear on the page.
What should I do to add a picture behind the form?

Html:Here in this section I wrote HTML code.

```
<template>
  <div>
<div class="signup-form">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Bootstrap Simple Login Form with Blue Background</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" 
                       placeholder="First Name" required="required"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" 
                      placeholder="Last Name" required="required"></div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" 
                      required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" ` 
                     required="required">`
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm 
                     Password" required="required">
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" required="required"> I accept the 
             <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> &amp; <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="hint-text">Already have an account? <a href="#">Login here</a></div>
</div>  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    counter: 0
  }
};
</script>
```

Css:Here in this section i wrote Css Code.

```
<style scoped>

body {
    color: #fff;
    background: #3598dc;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.form-control{
    height: 41px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none;
}
.form-control:focus{
    background: #e2e2e2;
}
.form-control, .btn{        
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.signup-form{
    width: 390px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.signup-form form{
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 30px;
}
.signup-form h2 {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.signup-form hr {
    margin: 0 -30px 20px;
}    
.signup-form .form-group{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.signup-form input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.signup-form .row div:first-child{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.signup-form .row div:last-child{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.signup-form .btn{        
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #3598dc;
    border: none;
    min-width: 140px;
}
.signup-form .btn:hover, .signup-form .btn:focus{
    background: #2389cd !important;
    outline: none;
}
.signup-form a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.signup-form a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.signup-form form a{
    color: #3598dc;
    text-decoration: none;
}   
.signup-form form a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.signup-form .hint-text {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS' `position` property to stack an element on top of another. Here is an example.

```css
/** GENERAL STYLES **/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

form .form-group label,
form .form-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

form h2 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}


/** THE FIXES **/

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

form .form-content {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

form .behind-form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

form .behind-form img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="relative">
  <div class="behind-form">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/52e8d3454e56a914f1dc8460da29317e173edce7545972_640.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```